# Compile and run C program in Vim

Tags: vim, vi

I wrote simple mapping that compiles and run C program. It makes what I wanted, but it returns to vim immediately after program finish execution without waiting me to press Enter. How can I fix this?

```
map <leader>b :!clear && gcc % -o %< && ./%<<CR>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement waiting in shell: add `read` at the end of your command line:

```
clear && gcc % -o %< && ./%< && read
```